# Oracle Transparent Application Continuity and Python

Tags: python, oracle

I am testing Oracle TAC and Python.   I ma using Python 3.11 and oracledb using thick mode for the connection.  When i run a query and kill a node on my Oracle RAC it fails over to the other node no problem.  If I run a DML command it kills the connection and I can't figure out why.  It works when I test it through sqlplus and JAVA so I know the DB and service are setup correctly.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is what I have.

My python code.

```py
import oracledb
import db_config
import threading
import time

# Create a Connection Pool
pool = oracledb.create_pool(user=db_config.user,password=db_config.pw,dsn=db_config.dsn, min=4, max=5,increment=1,events=True,getmode=oracledb.POOL_GETMODE_NOWAIT)


def run_update():
    with pool.acquire() as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            conn.autocommit = False
            print("run_update(): beginning execute...")
            cursor.execute("SELECT sys_context('USERENV','INSTANCE_NAME') AS Instance FROM dual")
            res, = cursor.fetchone()
            print("Connected to instance: " +res)
            input("Press the Enter key to continue: ") 
            print("run_update(): beginning update...")
            sql = """SELECT UNIQUE CLIENT_DRIVER
                FROM V$SESSION_CONNECT_INFO
                 WHERE SID = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SID')"""
            for r, in cursor.execute(sql):
             print(r)
            # populate table with a few rows
            stmt = "Update test SET v=UPPER(v) Where ID=:n"
            try:
                for i in range(5000):
                   cursor.execute(stmt, {'n': i})
                   if i == 250:
                     print("kill node")
                     input("Press the Enter key to continue: ") 
                     i = i + 1
            except oracledb.DatabaseError as e:
                print(e)
            else:
             cursor.execute("SELECT sys_context('USERENV','INSTANCE_NAME') AS Instance FROM dual")
             res, = cursor.fetchone()
             print("after stop connected to instance: " +res)
    

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=run_update)
thread1.start()


print("All done!")
```

My service config

```
Service name: pdb_tac
Server pool:
Cardinality: 2
Service role: PRIMARY
Management policy: AUTOMATIC
DTP transaction: false
AQ HA notifications: true
Global: false
Commit Outcome: true
Failover type: AUTO
Failover method:
Failover retries: 1
Failover delay: 3
Failover restore: AUTO
Connection Load Balancing Goal: LONG
Runtime Load Balancing Goal: NONE
TAF policy specification: NONE
Edition:
Pluggable database name: pdb
Hub service:
Maximum lag time: ANY
SQL Translation Profile:
Retention: 86400 seconds
Replay Initiation Time: 600 seconds
Drain timeout: 30 seconds
Stop option: immediate
Session State Consistency: AUTO
GSM Flags: 0
Service is enabled
Preferred instances: orcl1,orcl2
Available instances:
CSS critical: no
Service uses Java: false
```

My connection string

```
'(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=60)(RETRY_COUNT=30)(RETRY_DELAY=3)(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=4)(FAILOVER=ON)(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=rac-scan.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME = pdb_tac.localdomain)))'
```

My error message

```
run_update(): beginning execute...
Connected to instance: orcl2
Press the Enter key to continue:
run_update(): beginning update...
python-oracledb thk : 1.4.2
kill node
Press the Enter key to continue:
DPY-4011: the database or network closed the connection
DPI-1080: connection was closed by ORA-41429
```

Comment: your code doesn't align properly, also increase the stop number to see when you git the barrier

Comment: It must have been the way i pasted into the webpage.  I am confused on what you mean by increase stop number to see when you get the barrier.  how do I do that?

Comment: i mean `if i == 250:` inceease the 250 to 1000 and see what happens, it could be a time out error, so you should check the configuration and the time till the connction closes

Comment: One tip: run acchk to evaluate your code, see https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/newft/application-continuity-protection-check.html#GUID-55593F2C-9A1C-4E13-A225-2745F20C66F0

Comment: IMHO TAC was first implemented in JDBC drivers and then (possibly) in OCI. When I was playing with it TAC was implemented only in JDBC. Also it is not documented how many transactions can a session remember. When you exceed certain threshold, killed session is not replayed. TAC seems to a another great feature from Oracle which is not properly documented, sparsely used and possibly buggy.